# how can i override the saved image in external storage android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I create a method that save an image in external storage. Next time when i recall this method it cant save an image because with that name image already saved. Is there any way to override that already saved image.

Comment: please have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether an image already exists with the same name. then delete the image if exists. and then store the new image .

Comment: is there any other way to update or override that image

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method -

```
/**
 * We need to notify the MediaScanner when a new file is created.
 * In this way all the gallery applications will be notified too.
 *
 * @param filepath
 */
private void updateMedia( String filepath ) {
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "updateMedia: " + filepath );
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile( getApplicationContext(), new String[] { filepath }, null, null );
}
```

Comment: i want that method which 1st time create image and then next time automatic update that image

Comment: You can surely call this method on your created method and maintain some checks like if image file exists then updateMedia called and if image file not exists then create new.

Comment: ok Thanks and my reputation is not enough to vote your answer

Comment: Kindly make my answer accepted.There is a right icon below up and down vote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82556/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-hassan-usman).